# Emprego de ponto e vírgula

Tags: pontuação

Ponto e virgula (`;`), indica uma pausa maior do que a vírgula e menor do que o ponto final. É muito comum empregar ponto e vírgula após dois ponto (`:`).

Exemplo:

> No zoológico, podemos encontrar os seguintes animais:
>   leão;
>   elefante;
>   onça;
>  
>   macaco;
>   etc.

Outro exemplo diferente:

> O leão fica no setor A; o elefante no setor B.

Existem algumas frases que podemos ter dúvidas se empregamos vírgula ou ponto e vírgula. Como podemos diferenciar isso?

Comment: `Existem algumas frases` Quais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ponto e vírgula indica uma pausa maior que a vírgula e menor que o ponto. Quanto à melodia da frase, indica um tom ligeiramente descendente, mas capaz de assinalar que o período não terminou. Emprega-se nos seguintes casos:

- Para separar orações coordenadas não unidas por conjunção, que guardem relação entre si.

Por exemplo:

> O rio está poluído; os peixes estão mortos.

- Para separar orações coordenadas, quando pelo menos uma delas já possui elementos separados por vírgula.

Por exemplo:

> O resultado final foi o seguinte: dez professores votaram a favor do acordo; nove, contra.

- Para separar itens de uma enumeração.

Por exemplo:

> No parque de diversões, as crianças encontram:
>   brinquedos;
>   balões;
>   pipoca.

- Para alongar a pausa de conjunções adversativas (mas, porém, contudo, todavia, entretanto, etc.) , substituindo, assim, a vírgula.

Por exemplo:

> Gostaria de vê-lo hoje; todavia, só o verei amanhã.

- Para separar orações coordenadas adversativas quando a conjunção aparecer no meio da oração.

Por exemplo:

> Esperava encontrar todos os produtos no supermercado; obtive, porém, apenas alguns.

[Tirei daqui](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono31.php).